# My button that takes to a link does not work

Tags: html

I was making my HTML and suddenly my button wouldn't work

```
<button class="button.hover:links" formaction="Link here">Next</button>
```

So how to make it work because ever since yesterday it wouldn't work

Comment: what part of the button is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I am not sure why you chose the [`formaction`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_formaction.asp) attribute as the destination URL to link there.

The button with the `formaction` attribute should be working inside <form> tag.

The `formaction` attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.

The formaction attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit".

If you want a button which link to a URL you should make a button inside the <a> tag.

```
<a href="your URL"> <button class="your class">HTML here</button> </>
```

Second, it doesn’t make sense you put a class name as a CSS recognizable string.

You should define CSS independently and import that to use. Or you can use `style` attribute to set inline CSS.

```
import "index.css"
<button class="myclass">
...
```

#### File *index.css*

```
button.myclass:hover{
    // Your style
}
```

Comment: Alonso, so you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, [formaction](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_formaction.asp) isn't a typo - `form` + `action`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link something to a button, you can do something like this:

```
<a href="INSERT LINK HERE">
    <button class="button.hover:links" formaction="HTML here">Next</button>
</a>
```